# Assembly TRISA/PORTD?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic

I've written a program that turns on a few LEDs on my PIC, but I still am not sure what these do:

```
MAIN    CLRF    TRISD
        CLRF    PORTD
        BCF     TRISA,RA1
        BCF     TRISA,RA2
```

So, I clear TRISD and PORTD then clear TRISA, RA1 and RA2. Clearing TRISA,RA1 does that mean that I clear pin RA1 so I can use it as an output or am I selecting banks? And when it comes to CLRF TRISD/PORTD I just can't figure out exactly what they are doing...

Comment: Does CLRF TRISD set port D as an output and CLRF PORTD just clears the value of portd or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write a `1` to a `TRISx` bit to make the corresponding port pin an input, and `0` to make it an output.

At power-up, the data direction is "input" so that you don't get any undesirable output states before you have configured them. Suppose one of the outputs triggers an alarm? So your first two lines are back to front - they undermine that strategy by writing the output *after* the configuration. They should be

```
MAIN    CLRF    PORTD   ;set output state before configuring data direction
        CLRF    TRISD   ;set data direction as 'output' for all pins
```

The next two statements set the data direction on two individual pins of port A as output, but again, it's dangerous to do that before writing the desired output state.